# Charging lithium batteries while supplying power to load

Tags: relay, battery-charging

So, the problem is that I want to charge (with 19.5v laptop charger) 4s config lithium batteries while at the same time supplying power to the load (In my case, portable speakers, but also want to use this setup for other projects). My original plan was to use a buck down converter with adjustable current and voltage to set the output to be about 2A @16.8v, suitable for charging. This means, when charging, the power will be spit between the batteries and load. I suppose this would be fine if the load wouldn't consume more than 30W.
If however it would be some 50W load, the batteries would not charge but discharge (cuz the current from supply is limited to 2A).
My solution for this is to create an extra path directly from power supply to the load with a 5 pin relay in between. When current is flowing from the charger, the relay would switch between the two paths, disconnecting the batteries from the load and connecting the power supply to the load.
I have no idea if this would work and neither do I know how to wire up the relay in this situation.
I also thought of using diodes on the batteries but diodes are mabye not a very efficient solution.

Any recommendations for an solution are very welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forget the batteries for a moment. What will happen when you connect the 30W supply to the 50W load? Will the load stop working properly?

Answer (score 1):

If the load is an amp and speakers, you can expect average power to be much less than peak power (unless you listen to continuous tone sine waves at max power, or maybe dubstep). With music, if it is listenable, not clipping like crazy, and if it's an efficient class D amp, you can expect a few watts average power draw.

So you won't have any problems, just feed the power supply to the amp and to the buck charger.

However you should add a filter on the input of the buck charger, to prevent its HF choppy input current from feeding noise into the amp through its power supply. If that creates a beat frequency with the switching of the class D amp you might hear some weird noises too. A pi filter (CLC) should work well, with a lossy inductor like a big ferrite bead rated for the current. Make sure it doesn't ring.

> but also want to use this setup for other projects

If you want to use it with a load that draws a non-stop high current, then you'll need a power supply beefy enough to provide both the load current and the charging current.

If the load draws intermittent current you could make a scheme that shares power between the charger and the load. But the thing would have to know about the maximum current from the power supply, which gets complicated.

It is simpler to get higher power 19V adapters for free from the nearest electronic recycling center, or from basically anyone who dropped their laptop, and thus no longer has a laptop, but still has a useless power brick.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but just one thing I don't understand, if I for example have a 150w adapter, I will need a buck-down module to limit the charging current to the batteries right? But because the batteries are connected to the load, creating a path directly from power supply to load will also mean the current can bypass the buck down module.

Comment: Yeah, it feels like some details are missing somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Your charger must have a power capacity much greater than the worst case load so that charging occurs but at a slower rate. The mobile senses its own current and voltage to prevent over charge durations >3.8V/cell at CV=4.2/ cell.

If your supply was maxed out and fully loaded then the battery charger would take too long during CV mode towards CC /20 to CC/5 cutoff.